# Tomcat redirect 'stderr' content to 'stdout'

Tags: java, tomcat

I have just migrated web application from Tomcat6 to Tomcat7.
But after this errors that appeared in application are logged to 'stderr.log' file.
When I have used Tomcat6 errors and output were logged to 'stdout.log' file. So I was able to see every information I need in one(stdout.log) file.

How to 'tell' Tomcat7 to log errors and output to 'stdout.log' file as it was in Tomcat6?

Comment: I have the problem the other way round. Tomcat 6 is redirecting stderr to stdout. But I want the channels to be separated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the logging.properties file in the `conf/` directory of your Tomcat Installation. This is the point where the general logging is configured.

It is in the [java.util.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) format.